# '/l/' in a URL of unknown origin

Tags: magento2, category, url, magento2.4.4

I have a strange issue with my project. After analyzing the log files, I noticed that in one of the categories, when using filters, a weird URL appears. The typical URL looks like this: `/data.html?data_lg=6+m`. However, somewhere in the project, there seems to be a redirect that leads to URLs like `/data/l/6-m.html`. I have searched through the source code, but I can't find the location of this redirect or anything related.

Edit. I find out that every category has these ULR-s, and every URL `/category-name/l/whatever.html` is redirecting to a specific category page

Comment: Did you check url_rewite table/URL rewrite from admin?

Comment: yes, there is no URL with '/l/', this is working very weirdly, this URL should throw 404, but it is redirecting to the category page without any filters, even if logs show that there is a URL with '/l/' for every filter in that specific category but every one of them redirecting to the same place